# Using GNU getopt in C++ to read command line both as with and without argument

Tags: c, gnu, getopt

I am using the GNU library with :: function so that it should accept my input from command line -p and -pc both. But when I am passing -p it throws me a segmentation fault. I have to pass the -p without an argument and then with argument 'c' from the command line. My code is below. Please suggest.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char op= '\0';
    char arg = '\0';
    while( (arg = getopt(argc, argv, "p::")) != -1 ){
        switch (arg){
            case 'p': op = *optarg;
                if (op=='c')
                    flagp = true;
                else if (op=='\0')
                    flago = true;
                else
                    cout<<"Invalid parameter"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I retagged plain [tag:c] because the only appearance of any C++ is the incidental output statement, which can't be the culprit.

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem is that I have to do two different functionality using same character 'p' as -p from the command line, and should work without an argument for which i am setting flagp as true and other should work when I am giving 'p' with an argument 'c' as -p c from the command line, for which I am setting flago as true. So setting flagp and flago let me print two different statement. For this I am using getopt(::) functionality so that p behave by taking an argument and even not taking an argument. Its working fine with an argument (-p c) but throwing me a segmentation fault with (-p).

Answer (score 0):

When processing -p with no option, getopt() set optarg as NULL, and the op = *optarg instruction leads to the segmentation fault. You need to check optarg is not null.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int flagp = 0;
    int flago = 0;
    char op= '\0';
    char arg = '\0';
    while( (arg = getopt(argc, argv, "p::")) != -1 ){
        printf("arg=%c\n", arg);
        switch (arg){
            case 'p': 
                if (optarg != NULL)
                {
                    op = *optarg;
                    if (op=='c')
                        flagp = 1;
                    else if (op=='\0')
                        flago = 1;
                    else
                        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid parameter\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("optarg is NULL\n");
                    flago = 1;
                }
        }
    }

    printf("ending...\n");

    printf("flagp=%d\nflago=%d\n", flagp, flago);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
>small -p -pc
arg=p
optarg is NULL
arg=p
ending...
flagp=1
flago=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

But what if there is a space in-between p and c like -p c or more than one spaces in between p and c. 

Its reading it as -p not as -p with argument c. Is there a little modification to be done to adjust that.

Comment: @maverick This cannot be handled because you set the argument as optional.